# Cannot update platform branch for Elastic Beanstalk Environment

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an issue where my EB environment tells me that it is using a "Deprecated platform branch". However when I try to update, the dropdown box for the platform branch is greyed out:

[image: Elastic Beanstalk Platform Branch selection greyed out]

**Question**: How am I able to update the platform branch and why is it greyed out?

Comment: Hey! Did you find any way to solve it? I'm just facing the same issue.

Comment: @CristiNica sorry for the late reponse. No, the only way it seems possible is if you completely recreate the environment using the new Node version, and then you switch you swap your domain to point at the new one instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means you'll have to create a new environment.
Each branch corresponds to a specific version of node.
You can't change the branch of an environment.
As this branch is deprecated, you'll have to choose another branch during the creation of your new environment.

Comment: Why though? Could you link some sources for this? It doesn't make sense for AWS to just make our lives harder for no good reason...

Comment: I'm sorry but this is not mentioned anywhere in the AWS doc, in my knowledge. With the AWS console, you cannot change the platform branch after environment creation. This is probably something not handled by EB. I'm not an AWS employee.

Comment: Please, if my answer helped you, can you consider marking it as accepted ? Thank you